# How can I show my submenu to the left side instead of right side?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is my site: https://myshopperbuddy.com/
How can I show my submenu to the left side instead of the right side?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

change css to:

```
nav.top_menu ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%; //change left to right
    width: 210px;
}
```

Comment: It's not working when I add the code to style.css can I have your skype id, please? I really need to fix this.